# Why no [rule-of-five]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

(This is about C++-related tags)

We have a "rule-of-zero" and "rule-of-three" tags, but no "rule-of-five". How come? Should the "rule-of-five" questions really go into "rule-of-three"?

Comment: Presumably because it hasn't' been created/used yet. (well, until today)

Comment: However... how many of the "rule of three" questions on stackoverflow are really in any way related to said rule? a Quick glance over them... and i'm not sure they really benefit from the tag. there's only 53 of them. Most appear to just be syntax/debugging questions that just so happen to be trying to implement said rule.

Comment: @user400654: I was just answering a question about applying the rule of five (although it got [migrated to CR.SX](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233365)), and wanted to tag it rule-of-five - since it really wasn't a rule-of-three question.

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment on @CodyGray's answer and his comment latet, I suggest:

1. Have a [rule-of-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-n) tag.
2. Make [rule-of-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-zero), [rule-of-three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-three), [rule-of-five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-five) synonyms of that tag.

Answer (score -1):

Having separate tags for [rule-of-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-zero), [rule-of-three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-three), and [rule-of-five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-five) does not seem in any way useful to me. Instead, I would propose making these all synonyms of some broader tag that refers to the same concept.

I propose synonymizing and merging with the master tag [raii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raii).

Thoughts or complaints before I pull the trigger here?

Comment: I disagree. RAII is about more than these rules, and these rules are relevant for non-RAII classes as well. How about: `cpp-rule-of-n`?

Comment: Fair point. I'm OK with [[tag:rule-of-n]], but we definitely don't need the "cpp" prefix (and even if we were going to have a prefix, it should be the same as the C++ tag). Is there no larger concept that encompasses the *purpose* for these rules? I should know the name of the design pattern, but RAII was all I could come up with.

Comment: Not sure if it belongs in the RAII tag. But I would probably be okay with a rule-of-n tag.