# Unify/combine rule-of-three and rule-of-five (and possibly rule-of-zero)

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Please have a look at:

- [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) on cppreference
- [Obligatory Monty Python bit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOrgLj9lOwk)

This can be thought of as a single rule, or aspects of a single rule. It used to be called "The Rule of Three" because of three relevant methods, then the "Rule of Five" because two additional methods joined this set with C++11, and "Rule of Zero" because you should either have all these methods or possibly none of them, and having none of them is often a good idea.

We have all tags: [rule-of-three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-three) (64 questions, [rule-of-five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-five) (15 questions), [rule-of-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-zero) (16 questions). The first has the most questions since it's the oldest.

I once [complained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391840/why-no-rule-of-five) about the lack of a rule-of-five tag. That was downvoted - and rightly so. The top-voted answer suggested, basically, what I'm suggesting now: That there be a single tag for all three. The name could be "rule-of-3/5/0" (if we can have slashes) or "rule-of-five" with the other variants being synonyms.

But somehow, that's not what happened, and the different tags gradually gain questions. Please act... :-(

Comment: Maybe a frame challenge but - when are these tags appropriate to use? When do they add useful information/context to a question that isn't served by other tags? I should note: I'm not very well versed in C++ but these tags seem a bit vague to me. There is no actual usage guidance for them, as well.

Comment: None of the three tags has usage guidance. 'rule-of-five' is empty.

Comment: In what way are the tags useful (not a rhetorical question)? Perhaps add some examples?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: E.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961811/must-a-c-interface-obey-the-rule-of-five) asks about appliance of rule-of-five to the interfaces. This usage of the tag seems to be pretty relevant.

Comment: According to the cppreference, the rule-of-zero is about **ownership**. So it doesn't look like a candidate to be unified/combined with rule-of-three and rule-of-file, which are about **definition** of the special methods.

Comment: @VLAZ: So, you're asking whether we shouldn't burninate these tags altogether? I would say that these rules are enough of an idiom that merely saying "you have a rule of 5 situation" can be a valid answer to a question (if the OP knew what the rule-of-5 was...) - and that's enough for a tag. For a recent example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72571392/1593077).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: That makes sense, because it's a "wild growth" kind of a tag. People just start typing "rule-of", they see the "three", and think "oh, but I want to say five", so they type in the five regardless of the usage guidance.

Comment: @einpoklum but we don't use tags based on the answers. When should a question be tagged with any of the rule tags to begin with?

Comment: @VLAZ: The question does not have to mention "rule of 0/3/5" in order for it to qualify for the tag. It's the scenario/problem that merits the tag. Think of [most-vexing-parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse); usually what happens is that someone is complaining about the compiler not accepting their code, and an answer tells them: "Congrats, you've encountered the most vexing parse", and slaps the tag on.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: 1. I don't have a strong opinion on whether to combine all three or just the 3+5. However - I wouldn't say that the rule of 0 is about ownership while the other two are not-about-ownership. It's a question of whether the class or the members own the resources.

Comment: @einpoklum what *is* the situation that merits the tag? That's what I've been asking and hasn't been explained. Again, I remind you there is no tag guidance and I don't really know enough to judge. The tag only includes an explanation of *what* the rule is, not when one should use the tag. Is there really a "Rule of 3" question? Or are the questions about something different that happens to match the rule?

Comment: @VLAZ: When a poster's code has a class with at least one, but less than five, of those methods implemented, and the implementation does some resource-management work (e.g. memory allocation or de-allocation, starting a network connection etc) - I would add that tag.

Comment: "E.g. that question asks about appliance of rule-of-five to the interfaces" isn't that question c++? What value adds having this tag but not c++ to that question?

Comment: @einpoklum so should they all be synonyms of [`resource-management`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resource-management)?  Missing in your question is a proposal of what to unify them _to_.

Comment: @Braiam: The same kind of value that any specific C++-only tag adds.

Comment: @DanielWiddis: Edited to suggest a specific name.

Comment: You mean zero? Because I am sure that if those questions aren't tagged with [c++] no one will answer it, even if you use all of those tags.

Comment: "but we don't use tags based on the answers" We don't; but why not? By definition, the asker is not in a position of knowing best how to categorize the question, because the asker (at the time of asking) only knows the question, but the (correct) answerer (at the time of answering) knows both. Aren't tags supposed, at least in part, to help with searching?

Comment: Within reason. That a "great" jquery way of solving a problem exists, isn't evidence that this react problem should also have a jquery tag.

Comment: @Braiam: If you feel all "sub-tags" of C++ should be removed, then you are welcome to post a suggestion to do so. I don't subscribe to that view and this post is not the place to discuss it. Please assume such tags should exist and are of value, for the purposes of this request.

Comment: Pretty sure that tag is almost always an after market add-on. Usually rule of 3/5/0 questions are asked because the asker's never heard of it. That makes it next to useless for askers. From the other side I can understand the need to categorize and organize, but I can't really see anyone watching the tag who isn't already watching C++. I sit on the 'Why do we need any of them?" side of the fence, so I'm totally with merging them together and getting the noise down to one tag's worth.

Comment: @user4581301: 1. You're wrong. Just [go through the list for rule-of-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-zero) to realize that. 2. It's useful for answer authors,  for finding other relevant rule-of-0/3/5 questions, when you're answering a new one, to check for dupes and if it's not a dupe - to find relevant material.

Comment: If we leave only "rule-of-five", what do people do that are still on a level of C++ before that? How would they tag their question with "rule-of-three"?

Comment: @nvoigt: They would have rule-of-three as a synonym.

Comment: The larger problem here is not the three unique tags, but that their tag wiki lacks usage guidance. Only [tag:rule-of-three] actually manages to describe that this tag has something to do with C++. If these are made synonyms then the tag wiki needs a big overhaul afterwards.